# Jquery unload is not working

Tags: jquery

I have problem with jquery unload. It Doesn't WORK !

JS code  :

```
 $(window).unload(function(){
  alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

HTML :

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RVuU7/

Comment: Looks like it was [deprecated in 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/unload/), so that could be the issue.

Comment: Many browsers block alert() in that kind of events, to prevent spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(window).on('unload',function(){
  alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

instead.
Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/v3J5t/
According to the `.unload()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) , it was deprecated in JQuery 1.8

Comment: Try clicking on Update/Fork or something on the JSFiddle page (in essence, try to navigate away from the page in the same tab) and Goodbye will be alerted

Comment: Chrome 39 here, in an incognito window, no addons are enabled. Doesn't work neither after clicking the link in the fiddle nor manually typing another address. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     alert("Goodbye!");
 };
```